# how to check if a property value exists in array of objects in swift

Tags: swift, properties, contains

I am trying to check if a specific item (value of a property) exists in a array of objects, but could not find out any solution. Please let me know, what i am missing here.

```
        class Name {
            var id : Int
            var name : String
            init(id:Int, name:String){
                self.id = id
                self.name = name
            }
        }

        var objarray = [Name]()
        objarray.append(Name(id: 1, name: "Nuibb"))
        objarray.append(Name(id: 2, name: "Smith"))
        objarray.append(Name(id: 3, name: "Pollock"))
        objarray.append(Name(id: 4, name: "James"))
        objarray.append(Name(id: 5, name: "Farni"))
        objarray.append(Name(id: 6, name: "Kuni"))

        if contains(objarray["id"], 1) {
            println("1 exists in the array")
        }else{
            println("1 does not exists in the array")
        }
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can filter the array like this:

```
let results = objarray.filter { $0.id == 1 }
```

that will return an array of elements matching the condition specified in the closure - in the above case, it will return an array containing all elements having the `id` property equal to 1.

Since you need a boolean result, just do a check like:

```
let exists = results.isEmpty == false
```

`exists` will be true if the filtered array has at least one element

Answer (score 27):

In **Swift 3**:

```
if objarray.contains(where: { name in name.id == 1 }) {
    print("1 exists in the array")
} else {
    print("1 does not exists in the array")
}
```

Comment: How to return an object on the successful comparison?

Comment: @Hemang use `filter` instead of `contains` if you need more than just testing condition.

Comment: How to check one more condition under where: clause ?

Answer (score 12):

//Swift 4.2

```
    if objarray.contains(where: { $0.id == 1 }) {
        // print("1 exists in the array")
    } else {
        // print("1 does not exists in the array")
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

In **Swift 2.x**:

```
if objarray.contains({ name in name.id == 1 }) {
    print("1 exists in the array")
} else {
    print("1 does not exists in the array")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are mainly 2 viable options here.

1. Use the `contains(where:` method on `objarray`. I'm just making a minor modification to @TheEye's answer here:

```
if objarray.contains(where: { $0.id == 1 }) {
    print("1 exists in the array")
} else {
    print("1 does not exists in the array")
}
```

2. Override the `Equatable` protocol conformance requirement and just use `contains`, like this:

```
// first conform `Name` to `Equatable`
extension Name: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Name, rhs: Name) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
// then
let firstName = Name(id: 1, name: "Different Name")
if objarray.contains(firstName) {
    print("1 exists in the array") // prints this out although the names are different, because of the override
} else {
    print("1 does not exists in the array")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A small iteration on @Antonio's solution using the `,` (`where`) notation:

```
if let results = objarray.filter({ $0.id == 1 }), results.count > 0 {
   print("1 exists in the array")
} else {
   print("1 does not exists in the array")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Name {
    var id = Int()
    var name = String()
}

var objarray = [Name]()
objarray.append(Name(id: 1, name: "Nuibb"))
objarray.append(Name(id: 2, name: "Smith"))
objarray.append(Name(id: 3, name: "Pollock"))
objarray.append(Name(id: 4, name: "James"))
objarray.append(Name(id: 5, name: "Farni"))
objarray.append(Name(id: 6, name: "Kuni"))

var oneExists = !objarray.filter{ $0.id == 1 }.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with me:

```
if(contains(objarray){ x in x.id == 1})
{
     println("1 exists in the array")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

signature:

```
let booleanValue = 'propertie' in yourArray;
```

example:

```
let yourArray= ['1', '2', '3'];

let contains = '2' in yourArray; => true
let contains = '4' in yourArray; => false
```

Comment: I believe the question states "array of **objects**" and not an "array of **string**" as you are providing an example for. So this does not actually address the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

I went with this solution to similar problem. Using contains returns a Boolean value.

```
var myVar = "James"

if myArray.contains(myVar) {
            print("present")
        }
        else {
            print("no present")
        }
```