# What is the swift equivalent to setting properties on `id`?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I wonder what's the Swift equivalent in calling a method on `id` in which the availability of the method is determined at runtime. Specifically I'm looking to do this pattern in Swift:

```
-(IBAction) handleEvent:(id) sender {
    BOOL didDisable = NO;
    if([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnabled:)]) {
        [sender setEnabled:NO];
        didDisable = YES;
    }
    [self doSomethingAsyncWithCompletionHandler:^{
        if(didDisable) {
            [sender setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

The biggest problem is that  `setEnabled:` is imported in Swift as a property (e.g. `UIBarItem`) and none of the following constructs compile

```
func handleEvent(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Error: AnyObject does not have a member named "enabled"
    sender.enabled? = false

    // Error: (BooleanLiteralCompatible) -> _ is not identical to Bool
    sender.setEnabled?(false)
}
```

Comment: If possible, implement this functionality using protocols. You could then change the `respondsToSelector` check with an `if-let` like `if let toggable = sender as? Toggable` (assuming a `protocol Toggable` with the `enabled` property).

Comment: Not sure, but maybe AnyObject?

Comment: http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/07/swifts-var-is-not-objective-cs-id/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211160/how-to-check-if-a-property-value-exists-in-array-of-objects-in-swift

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 2.0 beta 4, your prayers are answered; this code becomes legal:

```
@IBAction
func handleEvent(sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.respondsToSelector("setHidden:") {
        sender.performSelector("setHidden:", withObject: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly, I can't get it to _do_ anything for `setEnabled:` (it compiles but the button does not disable). However, that might be a temporary bug; since it works for `hidden` I think we should assume it's supposed to work for `enabled`.

Comment: I filed a bug on the `performSelector("setEnabled:")` issue. It doesn't crash but neither does it _do_ anything.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with `setEnabled:`, but in a rather strange way... `.performSelector("setEnabled:")` always sets the value to **true** and `.performSelector("setEnabled:", withObject: nil)` always sets enabled to **false**, regardless of of the value of `withObject:`. I think deserving of filing a bug indeed...

Comment: @RichFox How about `.performSelector("setEnabled:", withObject: NSNull())` ? I reckon that sets enabled to `true` ? The underlying cause is that `setEnabled:` expects a C primitive value (`BOOL`, which is usually a `char` `typedef`) and feeding it with an object pointer translates to `true` (doesn't matter what object it is) whereas passing `nil` translates to `false` .

Comment: @matt: Yes, there is something strange with the "enabled" property of UIControl. `[button performSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:@(NO)];` in Objective-C has no effect either, so it is not a Swift issue. But KVC `[button setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"enabled"];` works as expected. (As you already said, this happens only with "enabled", not with other properties like "hidden".)

Comment: @MartinR I'll amend my bug report. It might not be a bug in Apple's eyes, but I'd like to be complaining about the right thing, at least. :)

Comment: @adib You're not grappling with the question of the _difference_ between `enabled` on the one hand and `hidden` on the other. They are both BOOLs but parallel code behaves differently.

Comment: @adib `withObject:NSNull()` returns **false** although `withObject:` does seem to be expecting a primitive value as you mentioned.  Passing in either an `Int`, `Double`, or `CGFloat` returns **true**,... `Float` though is returning **false**...

Comment: @matt if you don't specify an object parameter with `performSelector:` (the _without_ object variant) whereas the message handler expects a parameter, the latter would take whatever happens to be in the stack/register (depending on which ABI you're in – 32/64 bits and Intel/ARM) at the time and use _that_ as the parameter. In other words it's the classic "undefined behavior" that C programmers need to cope with.

Answer (score 25):

You can in fact do it exactly the same way you were doing it before: by calling `respondsToSelector:`. Indeed, that is exactly what your proposed expression does:

```
sender.setEnabled?(false)
```

That expression is actually a shorthand - it calls `respondsToSelector:` first, and then calls `setEnabled:` only if the `respondsToSelector:` test passes. Unfortunately, as you say, you can't get that code to compile. That, however, is merely a quirk of Swift's known repertory of available methods. The fact is that, although it is a little tricky to get it to compile, it can be done - and once you get it to compile, it behaves just as you would expect.

However, I'm not going to explain *how* to make it compile, because I don't want to encourage this kind of trickery. This sort of dynamic messaging is discouraged in Swift. In general, dynamic messaging tricks such as key-value coding, introspection, and so forth are not needed in Swift and are not consonant with Swift's strong typing approach. It would be better to do things the Swift way, by casting optionally to something that you have reason to believe this thing might be and that has an `enabled` property. For example:

```
@IBAction func doButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch sender {
    case let c as UIControl: c.enabled = false
    case let b as UIBarItem: b.enabled = false
    default:break
    }
}
```

Or:

```
@IBAction func doButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    (sender as? UIControl)?.enabled = false
    (sender as? UIBarItem)?.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: So you're telling me instanceof is less smelly?

Comment: "...dynamic messaging is discouraged in Swift..." whereas the rest of Cocoa uses it heavily. I'll stick to Objective-C if this is the case.

Comment: You're free to do so! However, just anecdotally, I've translated all my own apps into Swift; I was using dynamism heavily, and was initially horrified to find `performSelector:` missing in action — and yet in every case I've found better, Swiftier ways - my code is cleaner and safer now. Not telling you what to do; just reporting my own experience. Plus of course even in Swift nothing stops you from dropping down into the good old Objective-C Runtime calls if you need them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using the `respondsToSelector:` method you could define a protocol instead. Then extend the classes you want to use that is already in conformance with this protocol's definition (**enabled**) and define the function with a generic variable conforming to your protocol.

```
protocol Enablable{
    var enabled:Bool { get set }
}

extension UIButton        : Enablable {}
extension UIBarButtonItem : Enablable {}

//....

func handleEvent<T:Enablable>(var sender: T) {
    sender.enabled = false
}
```

If you need to use it with an IBAction method a little bit of a work around is required since you cannot use generics directly on them.

```
@IBAction func handleEventPressed(sender:AnyObject){
    handleEvent(sender);
}
```

We also need a matching generic function without Enablable conformance so that we can call handleEvent without knowing wether or not sender is Enablable. Luckily the compiler is smart enough to figure out which of the two generic functions to use.

```
func handleEvent<T>(var sender: T) {
    //Do Nothing case if T does not conform to Enablable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround/alternative, you can use *Key-Value Coding*:

```
@IBAction func handler(sender: AnyObject) {

    if sender.respondsToSelector("setEnabled:") {
        sender.setValue(false, forKey:"enabled")
    }
}
```

This works with both Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4) and Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7 beta).